# Gradient with degrees and negative location swift

Tags: swift

Is anyone who knows how to create Gradient class for UIView with these parameters?

background: linear-gradient(0.82deg, #4AABE1 -47.03%, #002652 115.74%);

```
final class GradientView: UIView {
    
    var locations: [NSNumber]? = [0.0, 1.0] {
        didSet { updateLocations() }
    }
    
    var colors: [CGColor]? = [] {
        didSet { updateColors() }
    }
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    var angle: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet { updateAngle() }
    }
    
    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    
    convenience init(_ from: CGColor, _ to: CGColor) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        colors = [from, to]
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateLocations()
        updateColors()
        updateAngle()
    }

      func setGradient() {
   colors = [UIColor(hexString: "#4AABE1").cgColor, UIColor(hexString: "#002652").cgColor]
   locations = [-0.47, 1.15]
   angle = 0.82
   }

}

}

private extension GradientView {
    
    func updateLocations() {
        gradientLayer.locations = self.locations
    }
    
    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = self.colors
    }
    
    func updateAngle() {
        let angleInRadians = angle * CGFloat.pi / 180.0
        let x = cos(angleInRadians)
        let y = sin(angleInRadians)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 - x / 2, y: 0.5 - y / 2)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 + x / 2, y: 0.5 + y / 2)
    }

}
```

I have code like this but it doesn't look on my simulator like in figma, may be i use deg and % wrong?

Comment: Can you show the two different outputs?

Comment: A sample with expected behavior and current behavior would be nice to understand what's the issue.